# netcoreapp1.0 does not find net461 specific package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using VS Code to build a net core app. I need to use a NuGet package that is not supported, and therefore changed my project.json file's framework part to the following:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net461": {
    "dependencies": {
      "ScrapySharp": "2.6.2"
    }
  },
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Restoring the project seems to work and the package (ScrapySharp) is installed. However when I use the package, it appears that both netcoreapp and net461 look for it. While net461 finds and references it properly, netcoreapp throws the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ScrapySharp' could not be found
```

Is there anything I can do to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If package available only for one framework of two - you should modify your program code and do not use this package when compiled under `netcoreapp`. Effectively, you will lost some functionality of your app when compiled under `netcoreapp`.

If this suitable for you, then use preprocessor directives like this:

```
public void function DoSomething()
{
#if NET461 then
    // do something with ScrapySharp
#else
    // Say to your user that this feature is not available
    throw new Exception("This feature is not available on this platform");
#endif
}
```

Comment: How do I compile under net461? And specifically, what tells vs code to use both frameworks to search for the package?

Comment: When you put two frameworks in project.json, you project being compiled two times - one for each framework. `dotnet`/`msbuild` do this magic for you. And you receive two output folders with two "almost identical" files, but one compiled for one framework (and reference libs from it) and other for other.

Comment: Got it. So there is no way to run the version compiled using one framework, using packages referenced only by the other framework?

Comment: No. Thats two different frameworks and they are not interchangeable. They (their libs) even contain some different classes/interfaces.